# Latex: two empty pages out of the blue - how to fix it?

Tags: latex

I am writing some article in Latex. After i started a new section and the first subsection, i noticed that before the fcolorbox there are two empty pages in the output. I have no idea where they are coming from or how to fix this problem. I removed this fcolorbox and it was fine...but i need the fcolorbox there. I am thankfull for hints!

```
\documentclass[
   fontsize=11pt,
   ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[]{hintergrund_a4.pdf}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\zitat}[2]{%
   \normalfont\small
   \begin{quote} #1\par
   #2
   \end{quote}
   \normalsize
}
\setlength{\footskip}{90pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Praxis}
\subsection{Einleitung}
Wir beginnen unsere Praxis mit einfachen Beispielen für eine Tranceinduktion über die Körperwahrnehmung. Das zweite Beispiele für eine Tranceinduktion beinhaltet schon ein erstes und wichtiges Element für den Einsatz von unbewussten Bewegungen als Trancephänomen.
\subsection{Tranceinduktion}
\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
Lassen Sie sich den Klienten bequem hinsetzen und bitten Sie ihn ebenfalls symmetrisch zu sitzen. Während der Induktion können Sie in einer ruhigen Stimme mit dem Klienten sprechen. Das alleine kann eine Suggestion für eine Trance sein.
Den folgenden Text können Sie vorlesen oder ihn in Auszügen verwenden. Wiederholen Sie auch gerne Passagen, wo es sich anbietet.

\subsubsection*{Einleitung}

\zitat{„Sind Sie bereit in Trance zu gehen? – Dann lassen Sie uns jetzt anfangen...
Ich lade Sie ein, immer mehr im Hier und Jetzt anzukommen...
bitte genießen Sie die Möglichkeiten...
und während Sie Schritt für Schritt immer mehr bei sich ankommen, kann es sein, dass sie ebenfalls die Augen langsam schließen wollen, um mehr in diesem Zustand zu erleben...
Es können interessante Gedanken auftreten, oder anderes...
und sie können sich immer besser auf meine Stimme einlassen, ganz leicht....“}{}

Regen Sie wiederholt an, dass sich bestimmte Körperteile nach und nach leicht anderes und entspannter anfühlen können -- bis sich diese Entspannung, wie diese sich auch immer anfühlt, den gesamten Körper UND den Kopf des Klienten sanft einhüllen oder angenehmen bedecken kann. Verknüpfen Sie diese sich ausbreitende, und vertiefende Entspannung mit der Atmung des Klienten.

\zitat{„Und es gibt Leute die sagen, dass man in einem entspannten Körperzustand auch mentaler entspannt ist...
ich lade Sie ein, dieses entspannten Zustand zu erforschen...wie ist es, wenn man mental entspannt ist? Und während ihr Körper sich weiter, immer mehr entspannen kann...darf sich ihr Geist auch immer mehr entspannen...
und es kann ein guter Gefühlszustand sein, oder eine interessante Lebenssituation in der man sich mental entspannen darf.“}{}

\subsubsection*{Mittelteil}

\zitat{„Nehmen Sie sich den Raum und die Zeit, die Sie haben möchten, um in diesen interessanten Zustand zu verbleiben...wie ein Forscher können Sie die Details auskosten...Solange Sie wollen...egal wo sie sind, egal wie gut sie sich fühlen...einfach so.“}{}
Lassen Sie den Klienten Zeit und bestärken Sie ihn ab und zu, wenn Sie die Wahrnehmen haben, dass der Klient sich umsieht oder die Situation erforscht.

\subsubsection*{Rückführung}

\zitat{„Solange, bis die Rückkehr in die Gegenwart, in die reale Situation hier auf dem Stuhl, hier in diesem Raum in der Grünen Schule, immer interessanter wird...und Sie können sich an meiner Stimme orientieren, bis Sie wieder aufgetaucht sind...“}{}

\subsubsection*{Am Ende}
\zitat{„Wenn Sie zurückgekehrt sind, bewegen Sie sich bitte ganz leicht und lassen Ihren Körper sanft erwachen...zum Ende atmen Sie einmal tief durch und öffnen erst dann langsam die Augen.“}{}
}%
}
\subsection{Übungsfeedback}

Für die Kleingruppenübungen hat sich folgendes Vorgehen als nützlich erwiesen. Bedenken Sie, dass es auch darum geht, dass die gemachten Erfahrungen beider Rollen gut verarbeitet werden können, um ein Lernerfolg zu ermöglichen. Tendenziell haben die Feedbacks einen Schwerpunkt in der Therapeutenrolle.

\textit{1)  Vorschläge: Feedbackfragen an die Patientenrolle}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Wie hast du dich während der Übung gefühlt?
\item Was hast du gut gefunden?
\item Wie bist du in die Trance gekommen?
\item Was könnte die Therapeutenrolle besser machen?
\end{itemize}

\textit{Vorschläge: Feedbackfragen an die Therapeutenrolle}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Wie hast du dich während der Übung in der Therapeutenrollen gefühlt?
\item Welche Veränderungen gab es innerhalb des Verlaufs?
\item Was ist aus deiner Sicht gut gelaufen?
\item Was ist nicht so gut gelaufen?
\item Wie soll es beim nächsten mal laufen?
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Tranceinduktion 2}
\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
Lassen Sie sich den Klienten bequem hinsetzen und bitten Sie ihn ebenfalls symmetrisch zu sitzen. Während der Induktion können Sie in einer ruhigen Stimme mit dem Klienten sprechen. Das alleine kann eine Suggestion für eine Trance sein.
Den folgenden Text können Sie vorlesen oder ihn in Auszügen verwenden. Wiederholen Sie auch gerne Passagen, wo es sich anbietet. Als Erweiterung des ersten Vorgehens benutzen wir hier bereits die Hände des Klienten / Patienten, um noch eine weitere Ebene der Trancephänomene miteinzubeziehen.

\subsubsection*{Einleitung}

\zitat{„Sind Sie bereit in Trance zu gehen? – Dann lassen Sie uns jetzt anfangen...
Ich lade Sie ein, immer mehr im Hier und Jetzt anzukommen...
bitte genießen Sie die Möglichkeiten...
und während Sie Schritt für Schritt immer mehr bei sich ankommen, kann es sein, dass sie ebenfalls die Augen langsam schließen wollen, um mehr in diesem Zustand zu erleben...
Es können interessante Gedanken auftreten, oder anderes...
und sie können sich immer besser auf meine Stimme einlassen, ganz leicht....Nun können Sie ihre beiden Arme, mit locker hängenden Händen ungefähr auf Brusthöhe bringen, mit den Händen leicht zueinander gewendet. Lassen Sie die Hände erst einmal so entspannt stehen.“}{}

Regen Sie wiederholt an, dass sich bestimmte Körperteile nach und nach leicht anderes und entspannter anfühlen können -- bis sich diese Entspannung, wie diese sich auch immer anfühlt, den gesamten Körper UND den Kopf des Klienten sanft einhüllen oder angenehmen bedecken kann. Verknüpfen Sie diese sich ausbreitende, und vertiefende Entspannung mit der Atmung des Klienten.

\zitat{„Und vielleicht haben Sie auch schon einmal davon gehört, dass sich Teile des Körper ganz von alleine bewegen können? Ja? Z.B. wenn man als Beifahrer im Auto mitbremst, oder auch in den Außenspiegel guckt…oder das automatische Nicken und so viele andere Phänome von automatischen Bewegungen, die wir im Alltag erleben und uns so sehr daran gewöhnt haben…“}{}

\zitat{„Und es gibt Leute die sagen, dass man in einem entspannten Körperzustand auch mentaler entspannt ist...
ich lade Sie ein, dieses entspannten Zustand zu erforschen...wie ist es, wenn man mental entspannt ist? Und während ihr Körper sich weiter, immer mehr entspannen kann...darf sich ihr Geist auch immer mehr entspannen...
und es kann ein guter Gefühlszustand sein, oder eine interessante Lebenssituation in der man sich mental entspannen darf. Und ich lade Sie ein, dass ihre Hände und Arme, so wie (S/s)ie wollen, selber prüfen, ob die aktuelle Entspannung ausreichend ist, oder ob sich da noch etwas verbessern kann…und in dem Rahmen wie es sich verbessert / oder ausreichend ist, können die eine oder die andere Hand – oder beide Hände sich auf den Oberschenkel bewegen – ganz von alleine ganz so wie es gerade richtig erscheint…“}{}
}%
}
\newpage
\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
\subsubsection*{Mittelteil}

\zitat{„Nehmen Sie sich den Raum und die Zeit, die Sie haben möchten, um in diesen interessanten Zustand zu verbleiben...wie ein Forscher können Sie die Details auskosten...Solange Sie wollen...egal wo sie sind, egal wie gut sie sich fühlen...einfach so.“}{}
Lassen Sie den Klienten Zeit und bestärken Sie ihn ab und zu, wenn Sie die Wahrnehmen haben, dass der Klient sich umsieht oder die Situation erforscht.

\subsubsection*{Rückführung}

\zitat{„Solange, bis die Rückkehr in die Gegenwart, in die reale Situation hier auf dem Stuhl, hier in diesem Raum in der Grünen Schule, immer interessanter wird...und Sie können sich an meiner Stimme orientieren, bis Sie wieder aufgetaucht sind...“}{}

\subsubsection*{Am Ende}
\zitat{„Wenn Sie zurückgekehrt sind, bewegen Sie sich bitte ganz leicht und lassen Ihren Körper sanft erwachen...zum Ende atmen Sie einmal tief durch und öffnen erst dann langsam die Augen.“}{}
}%
}
\mbox{}
\vfill \newpage
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

There is an overfull hbox message for this fcolorbox, but i have this a page later again, without problem in the output.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Without seeing some compilable code, my best guess would be that the colorbox is too large for the page. If this is the case, a breakable box (e.g. with the tcolorbox package) could help

Comment: I ve added the header section. I cant insert the whole code.

Comment: Given your user name I have to ask: do you already know https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a `\fcolorbox` can not be broken across pages and your box is both too large to be placed below the section title and even too large for a whole page. That's why it is pushed to the third page.

This problem can be avoided by using a breakable `tcolorbox` instead:

```
\documentclass[
   fontsize=11pt,
   ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[]{example-image-duck}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\zitat}[2]{%
   \normalfont\small
   \begin{quote} #1\par
   #2
   \end{quote}
   \normalsize
}
\setlength{\footskip}{90pt}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Praxis}
\subsection{Einleitung}
Wir beginnen unsere Praxis mit einfachen Beispielen für eine Tranceinduktion über die Körperwahrnehmung. Das zweite Beispiele für eine Tranceinduktion beinhaltet schon ein erstes und wichtiges Element für den Einsatz von unbewussten Bewegungen als Trancephänomen.
\subsection{Tranceinduktion}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=lightgray,colframe=black,sharp corners]
Lassen Sie sich den Klienten bequem hinsetzen und bitten Sie ihn ebenfalls symmetrisch zu sitzen. Während der Induktion können Sie in einer ruhigen Stimme mit dem Klienten sprechen. Das alleine kann eine Suggestion für eine Trance sein.
Den folgenden Text können Sie vorlesen oder ihn in Auszügen verwenden. Wiederholen Sie auch gerne Passagen, wo es sich anbietet.

\subsubsection*{Einleitung}

\zitat{„Sind Sie bereit in Trance zu gehen? – Dann lassen Sie uns jetzt anfangen...
Ich lade Sie ein, immer mehr im Hier und Jetzt anzukommen...
bitte genießen Sie die Möglichkeiten...
und während Sie Schritt für Schritt immer mehr bei sich ankommen, kann es sein, dass sie ebenfalls die Augen langsam schließen wollen, um mehr in diesem Zustand zu erleben...
Es können interessante Gedanken auftreten, oder anderes...
und sie können sich immer besser auf meine Stimme einlassen, ganz leicht....“}{}

Regen Sie wiederholt an, dass sich bestimmte Körperteile nach und nach leicht anderes und entspannter anfühlen können -- bis sich diese Entspannung, wie diese sich auch immer anfühlt, den gesamten Körper UND den Kopf des Klienten sanft einhüllen oder angenehmen bedecken kann. Verknüpfen Sie diese sich ausbreitende, und vertiefende Entspannung mit der Atmung des Klienten.

\zitat{„Und es gibt Leute die sagen, dass man in einem entspannten Körperzustand auch mentaler entspannt ist...
ich lade Sie ein, dieses entspannten Zustand zu erforschen...wie ist es, wenn man mental entspannt ist? Und während ihr Körper sich weiter, immer mehr entspannen kann...darf sich ihr Geist auch immer mehr entspannen...
und es kann ein guter Gefühlszustand sein, oder eine interessante Lebenssituation in der man sich mental entspannen darf.“}{}

\subsubsection*{Mittelteil}

\zitat{„Nehmen Sie sich den Raum und die Zeit, die Sie haben möchten, um in diesen interessanten Zustand zu verbleiben...wie ein Forscher können Sie die Details auskosten...Solange Sie wollen...egal wo sie sind, egal wie gut sie sich fühlen...einfach so.“}{}
Lassen Sie den Klienten Zeit und bestärken Sie ihn ab und zu, wenn Sie die Wahrnehmen haben, dass der Klient sich umsieht oder die Situation erforscht.

\subsubsection*{Rückführung}

\zitat{„Solange, bis die Rückkehr in die Gegenwart, in die reale Situation hier auf dem Stuhl, hier in diesem Raum in der Grünen Schule, immer interessanter wird...und Sie können sich an meiner Stimme orientieren, bis Sie wieder aufgetaucht sind...“}{}

\subsubsection*{Am Ende}
\zitat{„Wenn Sie zurückgekehrt sind, bewegen Sie sich bitte ganz leicht und lassen Ihren Körper sanft erwachen...zum Ende atmen Sie einmal tief durch und öffnen erst dann langsam die Augen.“}{}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]